# Sqlite_binding methods

Tags: objective-c

How can I write this query without using stringWithFormat. How can I pass parameters to the SQLite Query. Now my code is this:

```
NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT name, char_code, sound, status  From Tmy_table Where ID=\"%d\"", i];
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I want to store my queries as a constant strings in separate file. Because of this I want to do it without stringWithFormat method.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString sql = @"SELECT name, char_code, sound, status  From Tmy_table Where ID=?";
sqlite3_stmt *stmt = NULL;
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [sql UTF8String], -1, &stmt, SQLITE_STATIC) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    // If 'i' was text:
    // if (sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, i, -1, SQLITE_STATIC) == SQLITE_OK)
    if (sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 1, i) == SQLITE_OK) // Note: 1-based column when binding!!!!
    {
        while (sqlite3_step(stmt) == SQLITE_ROW)
        {
            const char *name = sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 0); // Note: 0-based column when fetching!!!
            const char *sound = sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 1);
            const char *status = sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 2);
            // ... print the values or whatever
        }
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Failed to bind int: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Failed to prepare statement '%@': %s", sql, sqlite3_errmsg(database));
}
```

**EDIT** Changed the bind to `sqlite3_bind_text()` as `i` appears to be text...

Comment: What if: `NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT name, char_code, sound, status  From Tmy_table Where ID=\"%@\"", string];` if not ID but string..?

Comment: @adadboy Then you use `sqlite3_bind_text()` instead.  `i` is a very strange identifier for a string!  It's almost against the law...

Comment: @adadboy if the parameter is text, note that you still don't need to put quotes around the question mark in the SQL statement.

Comment: @adadboy Also, sqlite3 uses dynamic typing.  It's legal to bind an int to a column that is actually text.

Comment: @trojanfoe i is not text according to the question, or if it is, adadboy is searching on the value of a pointer (using `%d`).

Comment: trojanfoe , JeremyP I have solved my problem. it is working just fine. God blessing and thanks to both of you

Answer (score 1):

You should use sqlite3 host parameters and sqlite3_bind() to bind variables to them.  This would like something like this in your example.

```
NSString* query = @"SELECT name, char_code, sound, status  From Tmy_table Where ID=?";
sqlite3_stmt* myStatement = NULL;
sqlite3_prepare_v2(myDBConnection, [query UTF8String], -1, &myStatement, NULL);
sqlite3_bind_int(myStatement, 1, i);
```

Points to note:

- The two sqlite3 functions return error codes that you must check.  I've left that out for clarity.
- The second parameter in sqlite3_bind_int() tells you which question mar to replace with the third parameter.  The index starts at 1, not 0.

See also [docs about binding](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html).

Comment: What if the statement contains non-ISO-8859-1 characters?  Surely the string returned by `UTF8String` will have a different length to what was returned from `length`?

Comment: @trojanfoe Yes indeed.  Thanks for pointing that out.  I meant to fix it while I was writing the answer (I forgot about using -1).

Comment: @trojanfoe Although of course, the string, which is a constant didn't have any non ASCII characters in it.  Also, it's any non ASCII character that expands to two or more bytes, not any ISO-8859-1 character.

Comment: THis is what happens when you rush an answer because you know somebody else is going to get in with the same one and it doesn't help when they still beat you by two minutes :-)

Comment: Agreed; but if you're like me then you will copy and paste that code around all over the place. If you were really like me, then you will have all that crap embedded in an Objective-C wrapper object so that it manages its own memory ;)

Comment: @trojanfoe Actually, I don't use raw sqlite very much at all - I normally go for CoreData instead.

Comment: @JeremyP Yeah Core Data is a technology I haven't looked at yet (tl;dr)... but it's the way forward for sure.