# How to pass multiple values of type NSString together for a query?

Tags: ios, sqlite, logical-operators, sql-delete

I have a table (named, `tblUsers`) with 5 rows like below,

```
-----------------------------------
(string)    (string)      (number)
-----------------------------------
ID          NAME          Age
-----------------------------------
abc          H1            20
bca          H2            30
dca          H3            30
qwe          H4            35
poi          H5            25
-----------------------------------
```

Now I want to delete the rows having this IDs bca, dca, poi.

I know I can able to do it by using `IN` logical operator for `SQLite`.

And the query may be like this,

`DELETE FROM tblUsers WHERE ID IN ('bca', 'dca', 'poi');`

How can I programmatically append ' ' for each of the IDs?

Those IDs I've in an array, so I can use `componentsJoinedByString:` method of `NSArray` to join them, but I will also need to add it inside single quotes like this -> 'value'.

Comment: by loop you can achieve this...but you got every object of array separated...like 'abc' then 'bcd'

Comment: Don't know about the downvote but: Are you familiar with sql injection?  Do not append literal strings directly into a query -- use parameter binding instead (see comments on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21862265/using-nsstring-parameters-into-sqlite-statement-ios)).  At a minimum, the approach in the answer will fail if user names (like O'Hara) contain apostrophes.  Worst case, user could enter a malicious string.

Comment: @Anna, thanks for your comment. But in my case, I'll query on a unique primary key field which doesn't contains that `'` and any other malicious string. Its only made of a string with alphabets (like in my question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How can I programmatically append ' ' for each of the IDs?

```
NSMutableArray *arr = [YourArray mutableCopy];
for(int i = 0 ; i<arr.count ; i++)
    [arr replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:[[NSString alloc ] initWithFormat:@"'%@'", [arr objectAtIndex:i ]]];
```

Then use `componentsJoinedByString:` method of `NSMutableArray` to join

**Note:** Its not tested. Im writing to give you a starting point.

Comment: As commented by @Anna, This approach may fail, if your key value contains `'` or any string that would not be parse by SQLite. Be careful. However for my case this is perfect and a good start ! Thanks @Adeel.