# not able to insert the string has apostrophe into sqlite ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, database, sqlite

I am trying to insert the string values(Okra(Lady's Finger)) into sqlite.But the string has apostrophe. It is giving Error Message is =near "s": syntax error. I am using the following code.

```
-(void)insertinto_DataBase :(NSString *)str 
{
 homeDomains = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains
 (NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
 documentsDirectory = [homeDomains objectAtIndex:0];
 _dataBasePath = [documentsDirectory 
 stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Store.db"];
 const char *dbpath = [_dataBasePath UTF8String];
 NSString *insertSQL;
 if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, & _albumDB) == SQLITE_OK)
 {

    insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"INSERT INTO Details 
   (str) VALUES ('%@')", str];

    char *errmsg=nil;
    if(sqlite3_exec(_albumDB, [insertSQL UTF8String], NULL, NULL, 
     &errmsg) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Error Message is =%s",errmsg);
    }
 }
 sqlite3_close(_albumDB);
 }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For Escaping the apostrophe try to use the double-up the single quote character. Hope it will work. like `'M''Bunty'`

Comment: No, don't use double apostrophe, use SQL parameter bindings. Instead of using `VALUES ('%@')` in your SQL statement, use `VALUES (?)`, you'll need to use the sql_bind_text() function inside the sqlite_step() OK block later. Here's a similar Stackoverflow question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21862265/using-nsstring-parameters-into-sqlite-statement-ios

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using 'kitty's', use 'kitty''s'. :)

In your code,
add this

```
str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@ "'" withString: @"''"];
```

just before the `insertSQL =....` statement